# jsvc & Gradle - no console output, Gradle daemon crashes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jsvc, apache-commons-daemon

I'm trying to test my Java app with IntelliJ IDEA on my local machine (it is intended to be used as a daemon, therefore the use of [jsvc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html)).

For testing purposes I want both stdout and stderr to be output to console.
According to the jsvc help site ([jsvc --help](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html#Starting_jsvc)) setting `-outfile '&2'` and `-errfile '&1'` should redirect stdout and stderr to each other (as per my understanding).

In a normal shell (with these two options set) the daemon launches and outputs some stuff to the console, but when using a [Gradle Exec task](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) and the exact same command the Gradle daemon crashes and outputs to the files '&2' and '&1'.

The task configuration:

```
File jsvcFile = file("./jsvc")
File pidFile = file("./jsvc.pid")

String mainClass = "substupdater.SubstUpdater"

task run (dependsOn: [jar, jsvc], type: Exec) {

    doFirst {

        // Get the absolute path of all libraries
        String classPath = project.configurations.compile.join(':')

        executable(jsvcFile)

        args("-server", "-cp", classPath + ':' + jar.archivePath, "-nodetach",
             "-cwd", project.rootDir, "-outfile", "'&2'", "-errfile", "'&1'",
             "-pidfile", pidFile, "-procname", project.name, mainClass, "debug")

    }
}
```

Gradle daemon crash (gradle -d run):

```
21:57:52.911 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING
21:57:52.914 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: command '/path/to/jsvc'.
21:57:52.924 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTED
21:57:52.925 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started process 'command '/path/to/jsvc''
21:57:52.926 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner] waiting until streams are handled...
Daemon vm is shutting down... The daemon has exited normally or was terminated in response to a user interrupt.
21:57:53.528 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Removing daemon address: [some-address port:35450, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1]]
21:57:53.529 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
21:57:53.529 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
21:57:53.530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
21:57:53.530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner] Abort requested. Destroying process: command '/path/to/jsvc'.
21:57:53.532 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: ABORTED
21:57:53.533 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command '/path/to/jsvc'' finished with exit value 1 (state: ABORTED)
----- End of the daemon log -----

21:57:53.888 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientInputForwarder] Dispatching close input message: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput@ce9a99
21:57:53.888 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 18: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput
21:57:53.889 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: connection stop
21:57:53.907 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
21:57:53.907 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
21:57:53.907 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
21:57:53.908 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
21:57:53.908 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
21:57:53.908 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
21:57:53.908 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
21:57:53.908 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to specify the full path to the file descriptor symlinks (namely `/proc/self/fd/1` for `stdout` and `/proc/self/fd/2` for `stderr`) and now output is being done to console.

The Gradle daemon still crashes but I think this is due to Gradle not being able to handle that the jsvc daemon process kills itself(?).